# How do we use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $2^x = \frac{10}{x}$ for $x>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Intermediate Value Theorem states that over a closed interval $[a,b]$ for line $L$, that there exists a value $c$ in that interval such that $f(c) = L$.

We know both functions require $x>0$, however this is not a closed interval.

However, I went ahead on the problem anyway.  I decided to solve for x.

$2^x = \frac{10}{x}$

$x2^x = 10$

$x^2log2 = log10$

$x^2 = \frac{1}{log2}$

$x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{log2}}$

However, when graphing these two functions I found that they both met up at ~$2.236$, which is not equal to $x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{log2}}$

I am very new to Calculus and the Intermediate Value theorem and would appreciate a simple explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: $\log(x2^x)=\log x+x\log 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in one of the steps it should be as follows:
$$x2^x=10 \implies \ln(x2^x)=\ln 10 \implies \ln x+ x \ln 2=\ln 10.$$

To use IVT, let $f(x)=x2^x-10$, now argue that it is a continuous function for $x>0$. After this find two positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$. Then by IVT you can claim that there must be some point $c$ in the interval $[a,b]$ where $f$ takes the value $0$. This would mean $c2^c=10$.

If you try $a=1$, you get $f(1)=2-10=-8<0$, now try a value for $b$.

Comment: Thanks for the well laid out answer.  The one part I don't really understand is when you let $f$ take on the value $0$, meaning $c2^c = 10$. Why is this the case?

Comment: @HoratioNelson that part is the consequence of IVT. Since $f$ attains a negative value as well as a positive value, so by continuity it will attain all the values in between at least once. Since $0$ lies between  positive and negative numbers so the function takes on the value $0$ at least once. This means $f(c)=0$ for some $c$.

Answer (score 1):

The difference $f(x)=2^x-\frac{10}x$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. As $f(1)=-8<0$ and $f(10)=1023>0$, the IVT tells us that there exists at least one $c\in[1,20]$ with $f(c)=0$.

Comment: where does the interval $[1,20]$ come from?